# True or False statements of Splitting Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

Verify if the following statements is true or false:

**A:** The splitting field of $X^2-X-1$ is equal to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$

**B:** The splitting field of $X^4-5$ is equal to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{5}]$

*What have I tried so far?*

I have factorised **A** to give the splitting field $\mathbb{Q}[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}]$

And for **B** we get $\sqrt[4]{5}$

Hence I think **A** is false and **B** is true.

Comment: I think A is true and B is false (because there are imaginary numbers)

Comment: Splitting field of $X^4 - 5 $ is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{5},i]$

Answer (score 1):

For A: $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 5] = \Bbb Q[\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}, \frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}]$, since $\sqrt 5$ is in $\Bbb Q[\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}, \frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}]$ and $\frac{1\pm\sqrt 5}{2}$ are in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 5]$.

Comment: Does that mean **B** is false? If so, how would we determine what the splitting field is equal to?

Comment: What do you mean $\sqrt5$ *is* the second field?

Comment: Reformulated sentence.

Answer (score 0):

For B:  note that $X=i\sqrt[4]5$ satisfies $X^4-5=0$, but $i\sqrt[4]5\not\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]5)\subset\mathbb R$.